# is there any trouble with wmode and flash

Tags: flash, wmode

our site's user claimed us about display trouble wmode and flash.
he said:
 flash display was broken

do you have any experiment about it?

Comment: That's like saying: "My program doesn't run, because there is an error. Can anyone help?" - No one can, unless you provide some code or example of what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Setting wmode to transparent, especially when playing video, has been known to cause some performance issues... setting wmode to transparent when you don't have a background graphic will also cause some unexpected display issues.... but we will need more information if we are to help you.